Obsidian exported vault doesn't display Dataview tables properly
I have a vault containing several notes and one of those contains a table that pulls information from the notes. I'm using the Dataview plugin for this functionality. When using Obsidian, everything works okay, but when exporting, my table is empty.
My best guess is that the plugin I use to export to HTML (Webpage HTML Export) is loading each note in the background and converting it into HTML, but it's not giving enough time to some of the heavier notes to load properly before converting.
The plugin doesn't let me add a delay in the settings and I don't know what else to do.
Any ideas?
The picture below illustrates my issue 
Here's also a copy of the code I use to create my table. I don't think this issue is caused by Dataview itself, as I can see the table within Obsidian.
TABLE  
title as Title,   
FirstAuthor as "First Author",   
Year as Year,  
Contribution as Contribution,
itemType as "Type",
join(map(split(tags, " "), (x) => "#" + x), " ") AS "Tags"
FROM "Literature Review"
sort Year DESC


I don't have enough reputation to comment, so posting this as an answer.
Check out the Dataview Serializer plugin, which will generate Markdown output from your queries.
For example, you wrap your dataview query in <!-- QueryToSerialize: and -->, like the following:
<!-- QueryToSerialize: LIST FROM #quotes WHERE public_note = true SORT file.name ASC -->

and the plugin generates the following Markdown in the actual note itself:
<!-- SerializedQuery: LIST FROM #quotes WHERE public_note = true SORT file.name ASC -->
- [[20 years from now, the only people who will remember that you worked late are your kids]]
- [[A beautiful book is a victory won in all the battlefields of human thought.md|A beautiful book is a victory won in all the battlefields of human thought]]
- [[A busy mind accelerates the perceived passage of time. Buy more time by cultivating peace of mind]]
...
<!-- SerializedQuery: END -->

The plugin also keeps the Markdown in synch with the source query if the data changes, updating whenever the file saves.
Hope this helps!
